# Scanning I2of5 barcode with iOS

Tags: codenameone

With CN1 the mechanism to adjust the barcode formats recognised using Android is documented and appears to work.

Is there a similar mechanism to enable the scanning of different barcode formats using the iOS version of the scanner? Specifically I need to be able to scan I2of5 in addition to UPC & EAN.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this isn't mapped in the [iOS version](https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-codescan/blob/master/native/ios/com_codename1_ext_codescan_NativeCodeScannerImpl.m#L26-L28).

This is probably something that should be added to that project, there are several approaches you can take:

- Fork the project and hardcode the types you want to be there and install your own cn1lib
- Fork the project and add an API to configure the supported barcode types, submit a pull request to the lib
- File an [RFE](http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/) to add this although this will probably take a long time with our current workload